# Mongoskin throws MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

Mongoskin NPM package is used for Node.js to `find` documents in a remote Mongodb database. However doing a simple `find` operation is throwing a MongoError. Inserting documents is fine. What went wrong?

Using node v0.12.0, mongoskin v1.4.13, mongodb v3.0.4.

**Code**

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin')
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://domain.com:27017/dbname', {native_parser: true})

db.collection('animals').find({}, function(err, result) {
    result.each(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(err)
    })

    db.close()
})
```

This throws an error:

```
{ [MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' }
```

---

### Update

```
db.collection('animals').find({}, function(err, result) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err)

    console.log('result.length: ' + result.length)

    result.each(function(index, doc) {
        console.log(index)

        if(index == result.length -1)
            db.close()
    })
})
```

returns

```
result.length: undefined
null
null
```

Comment: Does your program working perfect if you comment `db.close()`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your program `connection` is closing before `each` finish its job. Try something like:

```
db.collection('animals').find({}, function(err, result) {
    result.each(function(index, doc) {
        console.log(index)
        //if each finish then db.close()
        if(index == result.length-1)
           db.close()
    })
})
```

Comment: The output returned is 2 lines of `null` and I'm not returned back to bash. Updated question with more details

Comment: Why its showing `result.length` undefined? What is output of `console.log(result)`?

Comment: If I add `console.log(result)`, it does not output anything... the cursor is just stuck there without blinking and I'm not returned back to bash